# Angular best practice to set class on DOM elements

Tags: angular

I am tempted to use jQuery for setting the class recursively on my navigation elements like this:

```
$('.navigation').find('li').has('ul').addClass('has-sub');
```

Is there a way to somehow do the same thing in the component's ngOnInit (or elsewhere)?

Edit:
Here is the navigation snippet, the idea is to put class "has-sub" on "li" Parent 1 & Parent 3:

```
<li>Parent 1
    <ul>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
        <li>Child 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Parent 2</li>
<li>Parent 3
    <ul>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Use the model luke. And put HTML-related stuff where it belongs: in the template. `<li [class.has-sub]="navigationElement.children.length">`

Comment: If you have a completely static HTML tree, then you shouldn't use JavaScript to add class on some of its elements. Just put it inside the HTML directly. Regarding the first question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2we_B6hDrY

Comment: It is static and I am currently putting the class manually in the <li> but it is prone to human error so I would like to avoid having to think about it.
So what you are saying is that it's not possible to use something similar to  `<li [class.has-sub]="this.children.length">` ?

Comment: It is probably possible, but why bother? If it's static, it shouldn't be modified every now and then, and a mistake should appear during the tests, or even during the code review. If it is dynamic, then you should have a component dealing with a data structure (the model) representing the menu elements, and use the model to add or remove the class depending on whether the element in the model has children or not.

Comment: That make sense, can you maybe point me to some resources on how to generate recursive templates?

Comment: They work just like you would imagine they work: http://plnkr.co/edit/AbnMzptGyegxmbnlFlGj?p=preview

Comment: What does `has-sub` do?

Comment: torazaburo, it allows to have different look&feel with an arrow and so on.